# jQuery script to automatically parse and preload image tags and background images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope it's OK to post this here, since it's not a specific question related to my code, however I've searched on Google and can't find anything. I know it has to exist.

I want a plugin or script where after the document is ready, it iterates through all elements and pulls out img src paths and CSS background image paths and preloads them. It's not entirely complex, but there's a lot of parsing that needs to happen if an element has a combined style, for example "background: top left #000000 url(img/blah.gif) no-repeat;" (I don't know off the top of my head if that's the valid order of those properties.) So I'd like a plugin where they've taken into account all the different factors.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Doesn't browser do that automatically ?

Comment: img src paths are already preloaded...the css background images wouldn't be if they are defined in a `:hover` state or something similar, but for those, you can create an [image sprite](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) instead of using separate images. Another option is to include the images you want to preload in a hidden div, though, im not a fan of that approach because it muddies up the document structure for the sake of presentation.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain it well enough. I want an image preloader so that I can make sure most of the images in my site are preloaded before allowing the user to access the website, and I want a progress bar. I don't use hover state images in the CSS, only background images.

Comment: You could test this plugin wich support background images too: https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Comment: @Gavin put up a loading screen at the beginning of your `BODY` that would hide everything and then take it down in `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`

Comment: @roasted Thanks man, that actually does what I want with their 2nd callback option that includes the number loaded and the total images (meaning I can get the loaded percent), although it only checks the background-image CSS property. I can separate any combined background styles into their individual properties and it should work fine. Thanks!

Comment: @crush $(document).ready() won't mean the images are loaded though, just that the DOM is ready. $(window).load() will be called when the images are loaded, but then I wouldn't be able to show a preloader with loaded percent.

Comment: @Gavin Yes it will. When the DOM is ready, all images will have been retrieved at that point, unless they are assigned to classes that aren't currently applied to an element. But you're right, this wouldn't help you with a loading bar.

Comment: Sorry, you're technically right - they will have all began loading at DOM ready, but on a really slow connection, with very large, unoptimized images, it's possible that they won't be fully loaded yet.

Comment: Do you mean the images will be retrieved, or loaded? If you're saying when $(document).ready() is called all images will have been loaded, that is not correct.